# Deselect (any) text programmatically Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, textselection

I am using Android Compose [ExposedDropdownMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ExposedDropdownMenuBoxScope), but its text can be selected with a long press.
Using [DisableSelection](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/selection/package-summary#DisableSelection(kotlin.Function0)) section does NOT help at all:

```
DisableSelection {
        ExposedDropDownmenu(){...}
}
```

How to disable the text selection for this case or deselect any selection detected? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `ExposedDropdownMenu` creates a new [Popup](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Popup(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties,kotlin.Function0)), which is a new window, try placing the `DisableSelection` composable inside the content of the Dropdown